# Запуск функций с декоратором

Tags: python, бот

В библиотеке PyTelegamBotAPI есть декоратор, который запускает функцию даже если она ещё не запускалась, как сделать такое же, просто декоратор я сделал, но как сделать автоматический запуск функции без понятия. Возможно ли в тот момент когда на сервер приходит update автоматически проходиться по всем функциям?

Пример из библиотеки PyTelegramBotAPI.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/bot/{}'.format(secret), methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
    json_string = request.get_json()
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
    # Эта функция обеспечивает проверку входящего сообщения
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return "ok"


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Hello')
```

Вот мой самописный декоратор

```
def message_handler(value=''):
    def wrap(func):
        def in_wrap(message):
            if message['text'].lower() == value:
                return func(message)
        return in_wrap
    return wrap
```

Но работает он только таким образом.

```
@message_handler(value='Бот')
def bot(message):
    vk.send_message(peer_id=message['peer_id'], message='Вы обратились к боту')

bot()
```

P.S Бота пишу под VK

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае чтобы функция вызвалась, её кто-то должен вызвать.

Поэтому message_handler должен внутри себя привязывать ту функцию, которую он декорирует, к обработке некоторого внешнего события. У вас же ваш декоратор функцию ни к чему не привязывает. Как по вашему этот код должен понять, что кто-то обратился к боту, если вы вообще нигде никак не отслеживаете, что такое такое обращение произошло?

Посмотрите здесь, как реализован телеграмовский message_handler:

`https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py`

Он заносит все задекорированные функции в специальный список, и у него есть код, который каждый раз, когда бот получает новое сообщение, он проходится по списку с этими функциями, и пытается применить их к этому сообщению в соответствии с настройками.